# What are valid primitive properties in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I try to map a column to a char data type in my model class I get an error:

> The property '[ColumnName]' is not a
>   declared property on type '[ClassName]'.
>   Verify that the property has not been
>   explicitly excluded from the model by
>   using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation.
>   Make sure that it is a valid primitive
>   property.

What are the valid primitive types for EF Code First?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is interesting but you really cannot map `char` property. I just checked it and if you want to have `char(1)` in the database you must use `string` property with following mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(p => p.MyProperty)
            .HasMaxLength(1)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

It is not only problem of Code-first. It is whole EF limitation because EDMX designer also doesn't show `char` type. I think allowed types will be same as described in [CSDL reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399548.aspx) for EDMX because code first is just wrapper around the same mapping infrastructure.

Comment: Hehe "What are the valid primitive types for EF Code First?"

Comment: Hint: The error occures also if you have a property with a private setter. In my case the property was in a base class.

Comment: I had a Check Constraint on a char field to make it equal to one of 2 characters. 
 If I didn't have `.HasMaxLength(1)`, it would allow the value to be saved without checking what it was, but if I had it, it would enforce the constraint.  Just an odd bit of trivia I found out.

Comment: There is alternate ways to tackle this issue for TESTING purpose only. Make the field not null to null able for time being from design mode. Sometime it is restricted SQL Management Studio. (Change setting  Tools -> Option ->Designer -> Table Database designer -> Uncheck "Prevent saving changes that required table creation"