# what is dataAnnotation attribute use to make column have single character

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, code-first

what is DataAnnotation attribute i can use to make gander column only have one character in my table

```
public class Student
 {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      [Required, MaxLength(50)]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

      public char Gander { get; set; }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.columnattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) attribute.

```
 public class Student
 {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      [Required, MaxLength(50)]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

      [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(1)")]
      public char Gander { get; set; }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[MaxLength(1)]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

The problem is that [char is not supported type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760765/how-do-i-map-a-char-property-using-the-entity-framework-4-1-code-only-fluent-a) in mapping and without change in EF core to support the type directly or introducing some [simple type mapping or mapped conversions](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2639292-support-for-simple-type-mapping-or-mapped-type-con) you are not able to map such property.