# Code first columns with type char(36)

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, entity-framework-5

So I have a UserProfile model class as part of SimpleMembership. In it I need to store a legacy identifier that exists in another DB of type `char(36)`. I'd love to change this to something more sensible like a uniqueIdentifier but that's out of scope for today's activities.

My current annotation creates a column `nvarchar(36)`

```
[StringLength(36)]
public string UserIdentifier{ get; set; }
```

I'd like a column of `char(36)` instead. Is this possible?

Comment: The answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760765/how-do-i-map-a-char-property-using-the-entity-framework-4-1-code-only-fluent-a) may help.

Comment: @sza No it didn't. I found a way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to keep with Data Annotations, then just simply use:

```
[StringLength( 36 )]
[Column( TypeName = "char" )]
public string UserIdentifier{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 10):

Ok. I found the answer myself.

If I create the following configuration class for my UserProfile:

```
class UserProfileConfiguration:EntityTypeConfiguration<UserProfile>
{
    public UserProfileConfiguration()
    {
        this.Property(p => p.UserIdentifier)
            .HasMaxLength(36)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

then override `OnModelCreating` in my `DbContext` to add this configuration:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserProfileConfiguration());
    }
```

then I'm in business and I get a `char(36)` column. Yay.