# Generate a CHAR(32) column in Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I want my `string` class field to generate a `char(32)` column in the database.
I am using Entity Framework 6.1 code first.

```
[MinLength(32), MaxLength(32)]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

This code generates a `nvarchar(32)` in the database.

If I add `unicode: false` in the `DbMigration` class (I didn't find an annotation attribute for this), it generates a `varchar(32)`.

```
Code = c.String(maxLength: 32, unicode: false)
```

If there a way to generate a `char(32)` column associated to my string?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14876602/477878) may be helpful...?

Comment: How didn't I find that question? I'll try both suggested answers, I would prefer the annotations.

Comment: `[StringLength(32), Column(TypeName = "char")]` generated the expected column type.