# Why does this LinQ query not like chars?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ query that grabs all the data it needs and consolidates it into a data transfer object, everything works fine EXCEPT it throws query exceptions when I set one of the DTO's members (which is a char) to a char value...

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException'
> occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

See the simplified query below:

```
var result = (from c in db.Foster_Carers
              where c.foster_carer_id == id
              join fc in db.Individual_Carers on c.first_carer_id equals fc.individual_carer_id
              select new FosterCarerPersonalInfoDTO
              {
                  carer_title = fc.title,
                  carer_forenames = fc.forename,
                  carer_surname = fc.surname,                                
                  carer_gender = 'm'
              }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Setting the gender to 'm' just won't work, syntactically it is okay, just not when the query is executed! What could be the issue?

Comment: what exactly do the exceptions say?

Comment: Are you sure that `carer_gender` not throws custom exception in property implementation when one sets 'm' there?

Comment: @MarcGravell - Sorry I forgot include that in the Q, the exception thrown is - _An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll_

Comment: Please post ToString() of this exception so that we can see inner details.

Comment: @yBee - the DTO property isn't throwing the exception...

Comment: `FaultException` would indicate it's an issue going across the wire, not an issue with LINQ. It's worth posting your WCF method.

Comment: Further exception info (just had to switch the service into debug mode to get this) - Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: @James - yeahh, learning on the fly ;) for the sake of what I am doing I can easily switch the DTO property to string, but I would like to know why this won't work... and not surrender to this issue!

Comment: @James - just saw your edit! Ohhh okay, pfttt what a strange issue! I did research prior to posting this question however it would have helped if I had got the _real_ exception information earlier (like you said). Thanks for the help, If you would like to post an answer stating the issue I would be happy to accept it :) Thanks again

Comment: @Sam I just made my comment an answer - "Convert to answer" feature on the comments? Might post that on meta :)

Comment: It's a database you are querying right?

Comment: @GarryVass - It certainly is, how come?

Comment: The query provider doesn't support it.  See James' answer below...

Comment: @GarryVass - yeahh I had already accepted that answer, thanks though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a limitation of EF because `char` is not a primitive type, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760765/how-do-i-map-a-char-property-using-the-entity-framework-4-1-code-only-fluent-a) for more details as to why. The limitation itself is also [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx).

I would suggest you just use `string`.

Comment: Interesting fact.  Thanks for the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same and had to store an intermediate value and do a conversion outside of the Linq query:

```
var intermediateResult = (from c in db.Foster_Carers
          where c.foster_carer_id == id
          join fc in db.Individual_Carers on c.first_carer_id equals fc.individual_carer_id
          select new 
          {
              oldResult = new FosterCarerPersonalInfoDTO
              {
                  carer_title = fc.title,
                  carer_forenames = fc.forename,
                  carer_surname = fc.surname,                                
              }
          ,   forConversion = new
              {
                  carer_gender = "m"
              }
          }).SingleOrDefault();

intermediateResult.oldResult.carer_gender = intermediateResult.forConversion.carer_gender[0];

var result = intermediateResult.oldResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from VS and MVC using c# then 
Get rid of the apostrophe's and use full quotation marks instead.

use

```
carer_gender = "m"
```

instead of

```
carer_gender = 'm'
```

I've found that C# interprets the single quote as a char type instead of string.

In my case I had

```
var _list = (from a in table where string.Concat(a.AbsenceReasonCodeID, "|", a.Description).ToUpper().Contains(vlsTerm) select new { value = a.field1, label = String.Concat(a.field1, " : ", a.field2) }).ToList();
```

When I used single quotes I got the char error.  Replacing them with double got rid of the problem.