# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char' in MVC

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code segment like the following:

```
var results = business.Where(b => b.Description.ToLower().Contains(request.ServiceName.ToLower()));
var bb = results.Where(r => !r.Zip.Contains('-'));
```

When I ran this I get an error message in the title. My queries return a complex type that I have defined, and one of the properties' of that complex type is:

```
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

I want to exclude all the entries that does not include dash in the zip part.

Comment: I'm running this without any problem. Maybe the problem is related to the Zip information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be double quote ...Contains("-").

```
var bb = results.Where(r => !r.Zip.Contains("-"));
```

In addition, you can combine two where clauses into one if you only care about final result.

```
var results = business.Where(b => 
   b.Description.ToLower().Contains(request.ServiceName.ToLower()) && 
   !b.Zip.Contains("-"));
```

***FYI:*** If you use Entity Framework, you do not need `ToLower()`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is an Entity Framework query, Char is not a primitive type, hence the error.  Try `var bb = results.Where(r => !r.Zip.Contains("-"));`

Found a similar (duplicate) here:  [Why does this LinQ query not like chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025665/why-does-this-linq-query-not-like-chars)