# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context C# Link

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that I am using to aggregate some strings with some manipulation [Replace]. 
So, I have two versions of query; one of them working and another one is not working [throwing an Exception] and I wanted to know why it is not working.

Working Query:

```
string.Join("",Context.Table1.Where(c => c.Column1== Value1)
          .Select(c => c.Column2.Replace("~", "~" + Environment.NewLine)).ToList());
```

Query that is not working:

```
string.Join("",Context.Table1.Where(c => c.Column1== Value1)
       .Select(c => c.Column2.Replace("~", "~" + (char)(13) + (char)(10)).ToList());
```

The only difference between them is Environment.NewLine and (char)(13) + (char)(10)

UPDATE: 
This is because char is not valid primitive types in EntityFramework. There are couple posts that explains this in details:

1. [Why does this LinQ query not like chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025665/why-does-this-linq-query-not-like-chars)
2. [How do I map a char property using the Entity Framework 4.1 "code only" fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760765/how-do-i-map-a-char-property-using-the-entity-framework-4-1-code-only-fluent-a)

Comment: Whats your problem with `Environment.NewLine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know that a C# [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) is 16 bit? So, not the same as c++ for example..

You should use: *(similar code)*

```
string.Join("",Context.Table1.Where(c => c.Column1== Value1)
       .Select(c => c.Column2.Replace("~", "~" + "\r" + "\n").ToList());
```

Comment: I knew char is 16 bit in C#. I wanted to know what difference does it make between Environment.NewLine, (char)(13) + (char)(10) and "\r\n". Why did you say that I should use "\r\n". What makes "\r\n" better than other two ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with char being 16-bit, as `”~" + (char)13 + (char)10` would be a valid string, although less readable (and probably less efficient) than `"~\r\n"`. The problem arises because such type conversion is probably not supported by the LINQ provider, so it cannot be translated to the underlying SQL syntax.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub, Thank you for pointing towards right direction. I found couple posts that explains the underlying reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025665/why-does-this-linq-query-not-like-chars and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760765/how-do-i-map-a-char-property-using-the-entity-framework-4-1-code-only-fluent-a . It is the limitation of EntityFramework where char is not valid primitive type.