# How to map string type property to char using Automapper ProjectTo in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, automapper

```
public class Team {
 public string Flag
}

public class TeamDto {
 public char? Flag
}
```

using Automapper, how can I map Flag string to Flag char?

Mapper config:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<Team, TeamDto>()
                .ForMember(x=>x.Flag, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Flag!= null ? src.Flag[0] : (char?) null))
```

I am getting the error when running this. using EF6 DbContext

```
dbContext.Teams.ProjectTo<TeamDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();
```

This is the error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
> method 'Char get_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be
> translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Does `src.Flag.Substring(0, 1)` work where `src.Flag[0]` does not?

Comment: @DM does not work as it should return a char, src.Flag.Substring(0, 1) returns a string

Comment: Right, right, my bad. It looks like EF doesn't have access to iterate the string's `char` array. You likely won't have to worry about non-ASCII characters in your flags, right?

Comment: @DM yes I don't

Comment: I'd try just casting the result: `(char?)src.Flags.Substring(0, 1)`.

Comment: @DM I am getting Error: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'char'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238368/discussion-between-jdidi-and-d-m).

Comment: The answer is: you can't. In ef-core there (finally) are value conversions. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6762719/861716.