# Mapping a Char to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Database table in which table i have a column that is char type. EF originally  is not able to map char types.

I did a bit search and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628881/what-are-valid-primitive-properties-in-entity-framework-code-first/6634829#6634829) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760765/how-do-i-map-a-char-property-using-the-entity-framework-4-1-code-only-fluent-a) but it does not solve my problem. Here is what i tried

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("****");
        modelBuilder.Entity<DistinaBase>()
            .Property(e => e.ProprietaCompomente).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(1).HasColumnType("Char").IsUnicode(false);
```

And in my model i wrote this

```
[Column("PROPRIETA_COMPONENTE",TypeName ="Char")]        
    public string ProprietaCompomente { get; set; }
```

So my question is: Am i missing something in my way mapping char types in EF?

Comment: What problem do you have with the code? Do you get an exception? Is ProprietaCompomente null after query? Or...?

Comment: @mortb The exception is thrown in my View when trying to put data on a grid. ProprietaCompomente in the table is a char type. If in my model i try to pass it as `public char ProprietaCompomente {get;set;}` i got the exception that EF does not maps char type. If i change it to `public string ProprietaCompomente {get;set;} ` the exception that is throw has with NullReffernceException because in my table ProprietaCompomente is char.

Comment: Note that column name above is "PROPRIETA_COMPO**N**ENTE" and the variable is "ProprietaCompo**m**ente"